# Is there a way to pass multiple arguments to a recyclerview adapter in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have 1 fragment , with a tab layout and 3 tabs
[image]

I am sending a bundle over to the fragment once each tab is clicked, and want to use the same recyclerview to display the data once tab is clicked.
Are 3 of my api calls (top stories, most popular, sports) are different, is there a way to have 3 arguments inside of my adapter and have the adapter only use one argument at a time?

Here's my adapter:

```
class NewsAdapter(private val news: List<News>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.news_row,parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)

    }

    override fun getItemCount() = news.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val newsData = news[position]

        holder.section.text = newsData.section.capitalize() + " > " + newsData.subsection.capitalize()
        if (holder.section.text.contains('U')) {
            holder.section.text = "U.S." + " > " + newsData.subsection.capitalize()
        }
        if (holder.section.text.startsWith('N')) {
            holder.section.text = "N.Y. Region" + " > " + newsData.subsection.capitalize()
        }
        holder.title.text = newsData.title
        holder.publishedDate.text = newsData.publishedDate.subSequence(5,7).toString() + "/" +
                newsData.publishedDate.subSequence(8,10).toString() + "/" +
                newsData.publishedDate.subSequence(0,4).toString()
//        "https://static01.nyt.com/"
        Picasso.with(holder.photo.context)
            .load(newsData.multimedia.toString().substringAfter("url=").substringBefore(","))
            .placeholder(R.drawable.worldnewsicon)
            .error(R.drawable.worldnewsicon)
            .into(holder.photo)

        Log.d("amer", "MULTIMEDIA$$$: ${newsData.multimedia.toString().substringAfter("url=").substringBefore(",")}")


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val url: String = newsData.url.toString()
            val intent = Intent(holder.itemView.context, SecondActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("url", url)
            holder.itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
        }


    }
    class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val section: TextView = itemView.section
        val publishedDate: TextView = itemView.publishedDate
        val title: TextView = itemView.title
        val photo: ImageView = itemView.photo
    }
}
```

Can I do something like class NewsAdapter(private val news: News, private val mostPopular: PopularNews, private val sports: Sports)
?????

How should I go about this, what is the simplest way?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to pass all the three lists, if those lists are presented in the same way you can create an Interface to them something like this:

```
interface News {
    fun getTitle(): String
    fun getBody(): String
    fun getImageUrl(): String
}

class Sports() : News {
    override fun getTitle() = "Brasil 1, Germany 7"
    override fun getBody() = "OMG"
    override fun getImageUrl() = "http://bla.com/news.png"
}
```

So the adapter have a list of News:

```
class NewsAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ViewHolder>(){
     var news by Delegates.observable(listOf<News>()) { _,_,_ -> notifyDataSetChanged()}

}
```

And on your activity you will change the list after receiving the list, here I'm using LiveData, but anything should do:

```
class NewsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

     private val newsLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<News>>
     
     private val newsProvider = NewsProvider()

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         newsLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
             adapter.news = it
         })
     }
    
    fun onSportsClick() {
        newsLiveData.value = newsProvider.getSportsNews()
    }

    fun onMostPopularClick() {
        newsLiveData.value = newsProvider.getMostPopularNews()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but are you sure? My api calls for Top Stories, Most Popular and Sports are entirely different, the models for them are all different as well.

Comment: If they are displayed differently maybe you should make one adapter for each case.
There is some ways using dataBinding to prevent some code duplication, check this article it's a bit old but still relevant: https://proandroiddev.com/android-data-binding-listadapter-9e72ce50e8c7

Another possibility is to convert the models to a common UI Model.